# Locate installation file I downloaded at home

Tags: software-installation, cuda, software-sources

The security of the network at my workplace doesn't allow downloads for many installation files. I have a work laptop and a desktop, both of which run Ubuntu. I needed to install a couple software packages, and successfully downloaded and installed the software packages by bringing my laptop home, but now I need to install them on the desktop. Would there be a single file or directory I can copy onto a flash drive for each software package from the laptop, and where would it be located? (is it an .exe file most likely?)

The libraries were CUDA Toolkit 8.0 - Feb 2017 and cuDNN v5.1 for CUDA 8.0, if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the drivers via apt, I think you're looking for the apt cache directory here: /var/cache/apt/archives/

If not and you've installed them manually, check your ~/Downloads directory.